# VB.NET SQL Populated datagrid to Excel template

Tags: vb.net

I’m a newbie and I have a problem in hand. I have four datagrids in my application which gets populated by a sql command. The datagrids are

Datagridview1, Datagridview2, Datagridview3 and Datagridview4.

I have assigned a button to transfer these to an excel template which is where I’m struggling. Basically when I click the transfer button I want the records displayed on my datagrid to go to a specific location in my excel template. For example

My excel sheet name is LossType.xlsx and tabname in excel is Type1

Datagridview1 should start populating tabname Type1 from B3:G10
Datagridview2 should start populating same tabname Type1 but from B13:G20
Datagridview3 should start populating same tabname Type1 but from B26:G40
Datagridview4 should start populating same tabname Type1 but from B60:G80

Sorry for asking so many things but I have no idea how to get this done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
Satish

Comment: Have you looked into Excel COM automation? Add a reference to dll Mircrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel to your project. You will then have access to the Excel application from there.

Comment: But I have no idea how to use it. I was able to add the Mircrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel to my project. But I'm a very new to programming so can you help me how to code using this?

Comment: @Shell any idea on the above query?

Comment: @Nizam any idea on the above query?

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft Office COM interop.

To get you started:

Add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to your project and also to the class in which you will be interacting with Excel (`import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` at the top of the class).

The create a new Excel application Object, like

`Dim Excel as Application = new Application()` in your class.

You might need to create an alias for your reference, by modifying the import statement to something like `import Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and then create the object with respect to that, i.e. `dim ExcelApp as Excel.Application = new Excel.Application()`.

The you can use the Excel application object to create a new workbook, and a new sheet and put your data in the range you want (by using the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects it gives you access to).
Or you can open an existing workbook (`Application.Workbooks.Open()` if I remember correctly) and work with that.

Once you are this far, the way of using it is vary similar to vba, so it should be plain sailing for you if you know how to write macros.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is i dont want to create a new excel and a tab. I want to populate an already available excel template

Comment: That's no problem, then you just open the workbook you want to work with. I can't remember the exact syntax, but something like `dim myWorkbook as Excel.workbook = ExcelApp.Books.Open(PathToMyBook)`, then populate the range, something like `myWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("B26:G40").value = MyValue` or do a loop and populate the individual cells.